# PHP Previous Dates not Working

Tags: php, mysql, date

having some issues with a date format. It's showing only the previous 30 days, anything past that it doesn't want to work. Any ideas/help is greatly appreciated.

```
$today=date("d-m-Y");
if(!$fetch_Tasks=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `due`<'".$today."'"))
    showerror();
while($tasks=mysql_fetch_array($fetch_Tasks)){

    $now = time();
    $your_date = strtotime($tasks['due']);
    $datediff = $now - $your_date;
    echo "<font color=\"red\">[".floor($datediff/(60*60*24))." days overdue] </font>";

    echo $tasks['task']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; consider using PDO / MySQLi

Comment: what is the data type of column `due`. Also I'm afraid mysql processes this (`d-m-Y`) as date

Comment: If ``due`` is unix_timestamp then `$today` must be `time()`

Comment: And if `due` is a date field then `$today` must be in Y-m-d format instead of d-m-Y

Comment: @scrowler - thanks - I figured I had the date format mucked. Appreciate it! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The dates need to be in the same format.
the function:
STR_TO_DATE()
can be used to convert both dates to the 'seconds since epoch' format
then the comparison is strictly numberic

So, `due`<'".$today." becomes

STR_TO_DATE(strtotime('due', '%m/%d/%y') < STR_TO_DATE(strtotime($today, '$m/$d/$y')
(be sure to use the correct format string for the dates)